# Connecting to Gmail with PHP

Tags: php, web-services, email, port, imap

I am trying to access my Gmail account through PHP. I tried code like this:

```
$mbox = imap_open("{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl/}", "my email", "my password");
```

However, after many variations of this code this didn't work, I talked to my web hosting company (Bluehost) and was informed that the error was due to a firewall on their servers. Getting a dedicated IP address would allow me to access port 993, but retrieving Gmail would still not be possible due to the firewall.

Does anyone know either:

-How to access Gmail with these firewall settings, or

-What web hosting service I could use that would allow me to do access email on an outside server such as Gmail

Comment: Can you access your Email using a standard client like Outlook? Remember the account has to enable IMAP on its options before it can access it's emails from an external client.

Comment: Hostgator has all the ports opened, they are using a blacklist in their firewall. You should also check other hosting companies.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation, I ended up switching to Hostgator and they have been great so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And BlueHost just said "can't"? No further offer to help?  DTMFA!

I presume you thouroughly searched Google's excellent help?

I can only say that I use [Hostony.com](http://hostony.com/) and they are cheap, offer great features and have probably the best tech support I have ever received.

Perhaps you could approach their tech support and say "If you can tell that your service can do this & how to do it, then I will switch to you".  Ask that of all potential hosts.

Answer (score 2):

If imap_last_error() returns a "Too many login failures" error
then go to https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps 
and choose the "Turn on" option.

Answer (score 0):

Qouted from:http://php.net/manual/en/function.imap-open.php

> > For those having issues with Gmail (my problem was : "too many login failures" on a webserver, but no problem on localhost..), instead of
> >     opening with :
>
> $inbox = imap_open($hostname,$username,$password,NULL,1) or
>   die('Cannot connect to Gmail: ' . imap_last_error());
>
> Use :
>
> $inbox = imap_open($hostname,$username,$password,NULL,1) or
>   die('Cannot connect to Gmail: ' . print_r(imap_errors()));
>
> You will be able to see the full list of errors that happened, and
>   hopefully it will guide you to an answer. In my case, Google wanted me
>   to unlock my account by typing in a captcha. But this error wasn't
>   clearly shown through imap_last_error().
>
> Cheers, PH

Try his suggestion and post back the responses.

Edit:

Found this thread: http://osticket.com/forums/showthread.php?t=2597
qouting one of the posts:

> This is an issue with your server configuration, not osTicket. You need SSL support  enabled. Contact your hosting provider or recompile PHP with ssl/imap-ssl

So yeah maybe your host service is at fault. Try that suggestion if you can...

Comment: I tried this and it still says:
"Can't open mailbox {imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl/}: invalid remote specification)"
I am pretty sure that the problem was that my web hosting company blocked port 993, so I am not sure of any other solution.

Comment: Edited to add new suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I copied and pasted your first code and got the "can't open mailbox" error. I removed the final / at the end to make it "{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl}"... now it works. Got to love the simple errors (although I don't think it is a error as much as probably a bug in the imap_open function...something that they forgot to check for at the end) that you bang your head over for hours! Hope it works for you if you still need it or somebody else that needs it, as well!